# What is the explanation of the first line of the function secret?

Tags: c

What is the meaning of the first line in the function `secret`? What is the output of `return secret(3,argv)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int secret(int argc, char **argv)
{
 *argv && secret(0, argv + 1) &&
 argc == 0 && printf("%s\n", *argv);
 return argc == 0;
}
int main()
{
 char *argv[] = {"hello", "XYZ", "123", "ABC", NULL};

 return (secret(3,argv));
}
```

Comment: Short-circuit boolean expression.

Comment: Do you know what `&&` does? You would also need to know about what *short-circuit evaluation* is.

Comment: To see the output you can just run the program, no?

Comment: `&&` is **shortcut** logical and... meaning, in `a && b` the part `b` is only evaluated if the part `a` is true. So that mess is just disguising a bunch of back-to-back `if`s. `if (*argv != NULL) if (secret(0, argv + 1) != 0) if (argc == 0) printf("%s\n", *argv);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
*argv && secret(0, argv + 1) &&
argc == 0 && printf("%s\n", *argv);
```

is a tricky (and harder to read, I think) way to write

```
if ( *argv && secret(0, argv + 1) && argc == 0 ) {
    printf("%s\n", *argv);
}
```

Comment: thank u , this is the first time that I see someone remove the "if" from an if statement.

Comment: Not that much helpful (IMO), as you left out the more "mysterious" part of the recursive call within the condition.